# Only allow certain users to view Exchange contacts in the Address lists

Tags: exchange-2007

On our Exchange server we have 100s of contacts that appear in the Outlook Address book under 'All Contacts', we want to restrict these contacts so only a certain number of people can view them and send mail to them. How can I do this? We have Exchange 2007.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about "Address List Segregation" for the "hiding" part of your question. The canonical paper from Microsoft describing what you want is [Configuring Virtual Organizations and Address List Segregation in Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/bb936719.aspx).

"Delivery Restrictions" will take care of your concerns re: limiting who can send email to the various distribution groups.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the easiest way to do this is going to be subdividing your contacts into distinct Address Lists based on who needs to access them, and then allowing access to the Lists per group.